# How to unbind ALT in Lubuntu (LXDE)?

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys

In Ubuntu when I hovered my mouse over VirtualBox and held the ALT key, it was sent to VirtualBox OS.

However, in Lubuntu (LXDE), when I hold the ALT key, it wants to switch between desktops and I can't use the ALT key inside VirtualBox.

How do I disable/unbind the ALT in LXDE, so it works in the VirtualBox window?

Comment: I'm hoping that this is the same problem I'm having now, 4 years later!  I'll have to wait and see when I get home, but I have a game in wine that needs me to alt-click, and I can't do it!

Comment: Hopefully you'll solve it with the answers here, @soong!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlike Gnome - the keybinding and mouse binding is controlled by a configuration file created when you first login - `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`

Open the file:

```
leafpad ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
```

search for

```
<context name="Desktop">
```

Just below this are the statements highlighted:

[image]

Replace `A-Up` with `A-S-Up` and `A-Down` with `A-S-Down`

Alternatively just delete the lines below if you no longer want any <kbd>ALT</kbd> key mappings.

```
<mousebind>....</mousebind>
```

You should be able to move between desktops with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and Clicking.

You will also note if you search for `A-Up` & `A-Down` there are various other similar *mousebind* XML tag situations where <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click are used  - you could also think about changing these mappings to be consistent.

Save the file, logout and login to test the new key-mappings

Comment: what is the code letter for the "Super" key?

Comment: Oh, it's `W`, I found the answer here:
http://dquinton.github.io/debian-install/config/lxde-openbox.html

Answer (score 1):

#

! Disable Alt key

keycode  64 = NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol

keycode  108 = NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol

! Enable Alt key

!keycode  64 = Alt_L ISO_Next_Group Alt_L ISO_Next_Group

!keycode 108 = Alt_R ISO_Next_Group ISO_Level3_Shift

#

Save the above on a file eg:"disalt"
and => xmodmap disalt